# pass variable through blade pagination

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I need to use pagination on a laravel blade, but from the controller comes another variable that does not pass pagination, how can I solve it?

```
<div class="main-content">
                <div class="breadcrumb">
                    <h1>Página de Cliente</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="separator-breadcrumb border-top"></div>
                <div class="card user-profile o-hidden mb-4">
                    
                    <div class="user-info"><img class="profile-picture avatar-lg mb-2"  alt="" />
                        <p class="m-0 text-24">{{ $customer->name }}</p>
                        <p class="text-muted m-0">{{ $customer->email }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs profile-nav mb-4" id="profileTab" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="timeline-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#timeline" role="tab" aria-controls="timeline" aria-selected="false">Propostas</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="about-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#about" role="tab" aria-controls="about" aria-selected="true">#</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="friends-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#friends" role="tab" aria-controls="friends" aria-selected="false">#</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="photos-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#photos" role="tab" aria-controls="photos" aria-selected="false">#</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content" id="profileTabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="timeline" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="timeline-tab">
                                <div class="row mb-4">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                        <div class="card text-left">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h4 class="card-title mb-3">Lista de Propostas</h4>    
                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                    <table class="table">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                                                <th scope="col">Data</th>
                                                                <th scope="col">Vendedor</th>
                                                                <th scope="col">Produto</th>
                                                                <th scope="col">Preço</th>
                                                                <th scope="col">Produção</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        @foreach($proposals as $proposal)
                                                            <tbody>        
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th scope="row"> {{ $proposal->id_proposal }} </th>
                                                                    <td> {{ $proposal->date }} </td>
                                                                    <td> {{$proposal->users()->first()->name }} </td>
                                                                    
                                                                    
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    @foreach($proposal->proposed_phases()->get() as $proposedphase)
                                                                    <p>{{ $proposedphase->features()->first()->name }}</p>
                                                                    @endforeach
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    @foreach($proposal->proposed_phases()->get() as $proposedphase)
                                                                    <p>{{ $proposedphase->amount }}€</p>
                                                                    @endforeach
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    
                                                                    @if($proposal->id_production == null)
                                                                    <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Produção</span></td>
                                                                    @else
                                                                    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Produção</span></td>
                                                                    @endif
                                                                   
                                                                    @if($proposal->id_production == null)
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="{{ URL::route('new.production', array('id_proposal'=>$proposal->id_proposal)) }}" class="text-success mr-2">
                                                                            <button class="nav-icon i-Add font-weight-bold btn btn-success m-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Criar Produção"></button>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </td> 
                                                                    @else
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="{{ URL::route('new.label', array('id_proposal'=>$proposal->id_proposal)) }}" class="text-success mr-2">
                                                                            <button class="nav-icon i-Add font-weight-bold btn btn-warning m-0" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Criar Etiquetas"></button>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </td> 
                                                                    @endif          
                                                                </tr>    
                                                            </tbody>  
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </table>
                                                    {{-- Pagination --}}
                                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                            {!! $proposals->links() !!}
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function PageCustomer(Request $request)
        {
            $data = $request->all();
            $customer = customer::where('id_customer', $data['id_customer'])->first();
            $proposals = proposal::where('id_customer', $customer['id_customer'])->paginate(5);

            return view('admin.customer.page_customer', compact('customer', 'proposals'));
        }
```

the variable that does not pass to the second page is $customer
I tried to pass an array with the values ​​of name and email, but it didn't work. how can i resolve this situation?

Comment: What you really need to do is to use the customer id in your route like `pageCustomer\{customer_id}\proposals`

Comment: what about it doesn't work? what is happening?

Comment: @lagbox when we click on page two, laravel reloads the blade with the updated foreach information for page two, but the $customer variable that comes from the controller is missing, I need to pass that variable to page 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `appends` on Paginator :

```
{!! $proposals->appends(['customer' => $customer])->links() !!}
```

As of **Laravel 7**, you can call the `withQueryString()` method on your Paginator instance :

```
{!! $proposals->withQueryString()->links() !!}
```

> `withQueryString()` method appends all current query string values to the pagination links.

Comment: Don't understand how this will help. The blade view has `$ustomer->name` and `$customer->email` values to be shown on the page. `appends` or `withQueryString` will append to the url query params it still won't be available in blade view. And can we pass an entire eloquent model object as query params?

Comment: @Donkarnash, you are passing query string, that passes through controller and send the object on 2nd page with that query string. The same method happens with `{{ $users->links() }}`, that gives you a query string like `?page=1`, `?page=2` and you get different array object on every page with that query string

Comment: Okay got it. In Controller Customer record is pulled based on request data - now I understand. Thanks